# How to input ui.R values as ncol and nrow values for matrix definition in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm providing user input field in ui.R of a shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(
            numericInput("n_sampling", "Number of Samples")
)
```

Then I want `n_resampling` be available to `server.R` as parameter for setup of a matrix:

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(
    function(input, output)
    {
        n_row <- reactive({as.numeric(input$n_sampling)})
        loess_functions <- matrix(NA, nrow=n_row, ncol=50)
    }
)
```

I get the message that there's an error in `matrix(NA, ...)` saying that there's a non-numeric matrix-extension.

How can I extract the user input value for `n_sampling`?

Comment: At server side, try `input$n_resampling`, maybe it is a typo. This should work: `matrix(NA, nrow=input$n_resampling, ncol=50)`

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try below example:

```
require(shiny)

#define app
app <- shinyApp(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    numericInput("n_row", "Number of Rows",10),
    numericInput("n_col", "Number of Columns",10),
    tableOutput("mymatrix")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    loess_functions <- reactive({matrix(NA, 
                                        nrow=input$n_row, 
                                        ncol=input$n_col)})
    output$mymatrix <- renderTable(loess_functions())
  }
)

#run app
runApp(app)
```

Comment: Ok, but why or how can i extract a value to use within the server function?

Comment: We **are** using input value on server side, e.g.: `nrow=input$n_row`